# Spring Integraton RSocket and Spring RSocket interaction issues

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, rsocket

I created a new sample and slipted the codes into client and server side.

The complete codes can be found [here](https://github.com/hantsy/rsocket-sample/tree/master/integration).

There are 3 version of server side.

- **server** None Spring Boot app, using Spring Integration RSocket InboundGateway.
- **server-boot** Reuse Spring RSocket autconfiguration, and created `ServerRSocketConnecter` through `ServerRSocketMessageHanlder`.
- **server-boot-messsagemapping** Not use Spring Integration, just use Spring Boot RSocket autconfiguration, and `@Controller` and `@MessageMapping`.

There are 2 versions of client.

- **client**, Sending messages using Spring Integration Rocket OutboundGateway.
- **client-requester** Send messages using `RSocketRequester`, not use Spring Integration at all.

The client and server interaction mode is REQUEST_CHANNEL, and connect server via TCP/localhost:7000.

### server

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-rsocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The application class:

```java
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@IntegrationComponentScan
@EnableIntegration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        try (ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoApplication.class)) {
            System.out.println("Press any key to exit.");
            System.in.read();
        } finally {
            System.out.println("Exited.");
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public ServerRSocketConnector serverRSocketConnector() {
        return new ServerRSocketConnector("localhost", 7000);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow rsocketUpperCaseFlow(ServerRSocketConnector serverRSocketConnector) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(RSockets.inboundGateway("/uppercase")
                        .interactionModels(RSocketInteractionModel.requestChannel)
                        .rsocketConnector(serverRSocketConnector)
                )
                .<Flux<String>, Flux<String>>transform((flux) -> flux.map(String::toUpperCase))
                .get();
    }

}
```

### server-boot

Dependencies in pom.xml.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rsocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-rsocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.properties

```
spring.rsocket.server.port=7000
spring.rsocket.server.transport=tcp
```

Application class.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    // see PR: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/pull/18834
    @Bean
    ServerRSocketMessageHandler serverRSocketMessageHandler(RSocketStrategies rSocketStrategies) {
        var handler = new ServerRSocketMessageHandler(true);
        handler.setRSocketStrategies(rSocketStrategies);
        return handler;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServerRSocketConnector serverRSocketConnector(ServerRSocketMessageHandler serverRSocketMessageHandler) {
        return new ServerRSocketConnector(serverRSocketMessageHandler);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow rsocketUpperCaseFlow(ServerRSocketConnector serverRSocketConnector) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(RSockets.inboundGateway("/uppercase")
                        .interactionModels(RSocketInteractionModel.requestChannel)
                        .rsocketConnector(serverRSocketConnector)
                )
                .<Flux<String>, Flux<String>>transform((flux) -> flux.map(String::toUpperCase))
                .get();
    }

}
```

### server-boot-messagemapping

Dependencies in pom.xml.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rsocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

The application.properties.

```
spring.rsocket.server.port=7000
spring.rsocket.server.transport=tcp
```

The applcition class.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@Controller
class UpperCaseHandler {

    @MessageMapping("/uppercase")
    public Flux<String> uppercase(Flux<String> input) {
        return input.map(String::toUpperCase);
    }
}
```

### client

In the client, the dependencies in the *pom.xml* is like.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-integration</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-rsocket</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

The application class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableIntegration
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ClientRSocketConnector clientRSocketConnector() {
        ClientRSocketConnector clientRSocketConnector = new ClientRSocketConnector("localhost", 7000);
        clientRSocketConnector.setAutoStartup(false);
        return clientRSocketConnector;
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow rsocketUpperCaseRequestFlow(ClientRSocketConnector clientRSocketConnector) {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Function.class)
                .handle(RSockets.outboundGateway("/uppercase")
                        .interactionModel((message) -> RSocketInteractionModel.requestChannel)
                        .expectedResponseType("T(java.lang.String)")
                        .clientRSocketConnector(clientRSocketConnector))
                .get();
    }
}

@RestController
class HelloController {

    @Autowired()
    @Lazy
    @Qualifier("rsocketUpperCaseRequestFlow.gateway")
    private Function<Flux<String>, Flux<String>> rsocketUpperCaseFlowFunction;

    @GetMapping(value = "hello", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> uppercase() {
        return rsocketUpperCaseFlowFunction.apply(Flux.just("a", "b", "c", "d"));
    }
}
```

When running the client and server application, and try to access the `http://localhost:8080/hello` by `curl`.

When using **server** and **server-boot** which uses InboundGateway to handle messages, the output looks like this.

```sh
curl http://localhost:8080/hello

data:ABCD
```

When using **server-boot-messagemapping**, the output is woking as I expected:

```sh
data:A
data:B
data:C
data:D
```

### client-requester

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-rsocket</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

The application class:

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}

@RestController
class HelloController {
    Mono<RSocketRequester> requesterMono;

    public HelloController(RSocketRequester.Builder builder) {
        this.requesterMono = builder.connectTcp("localhost", 7000);
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "hello", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<String> uppercase() {
        return requesterMono.flatMapMany(
                rSocketRequester -> rSocketRequester.route("/uppercase")
                        .data(Flux.just("a", "b", "c", "d"))
                        .retrieveFlux(String.class)
        );
    }
}
```

When running this client and the 3 servers, and try to access the `http://localhost:8080/hello` by `curl`.

When using **server** and **server-boot** which uses InboundGateway to handle messages, it throws a class cast exception.

When using **server-boot-messagemapping**, the output is woking as I expected:

```sh
data:A
data:B
data:C
data:D
```

I do not know where is the problem of the configuration of InboundGateway and OutboundGateway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for such a detailed sample!

So, what I see. Both clients (plain `RSocketRequester` and Spring Integration) work well with plain RSocket server.

To make them working with Spring Integration server you have to do this changes:

1. The server side:

Add `.requestElementType(ResolvableType.forClass(String.class))` into an `RSockets.inboundGateway()` definition, so it will know to what to convert an incoming payloads.

2. The client side:

   `.data(Flux.just("a\n", "b\n", "c\n", "d\n"))`.

Currently the server side of Spring Integration doesn't treat an incoming `Flux` as a stream of independent payloads. So, we try to connect all of them into a single value.
The new line delimiter is an indicator that we expect independent values. Spring Messaging on its side does exactly opposite: it checks for `multi-value` expected type and decode every element in the incoming `Flux` in its `map()` instead of an attempt for the whole `Publisher` decoding.

It's going to be kinda breaking change, but possibly need to consider to fix `RSocketInboundGateway` logic to be consistent with regular `@MessageMapping` for RSocket support. Feel free to raise a GH issue!

Comment: Created issue [spring-projects/spring-integration#3207](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/issues/3207)